# Why my unordered_map program doesnt function when I use a million integers of a value of a billion or a million or even 10 thousand?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

The task is:
Given two unsorted arrays and find all the pairs whose sum is between l and r (l and r given num).
I have used before the unordered_map and it could store big values and could work rather fast, but in this case it cant even store values over a thousand, when I try using integers smaller than a thousand it works very fast(A,B).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

long int counts(const unordered_map<long int, long int> arr, long int L,
                long int R, long int val)
{
    long int counter = 0;

    for(auto it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); ++it) {
        // cout << " " << it->first << ":" << it->second;
        if(it->first <= val && it->first + R - L >= val) {
            counter = counter + it->second;
            // cout << " " << it->first << ":" << it->second;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}

int main() {
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    long int N, M, A, B, L, R, counter = 0, key = 0, keyb = 0, sum = 0, a = 0,
                               b = 0;

    unordered_map<long int, long int> c;
    unordered_map<long int, long int> d;

    freopen("twingift50k.in", "r", stdin);
    scanf("%ld %ld %ld %ld", &N, &M, &L, &R);

    for(long int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%ld ", &A);
        key = L - A;

        if(A <= R) {
            c[key]++;
        }
        key = 0;
    }

    for(long int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        scanf("%ld ", &B);
        keyb = B;
        if(B <= R) {
            d[keyb]++;
        }
        keyb = 0;
    }

    for(auto it = d.begin(); it != d.end(); ++it) {
        a = it->second;
        b = counts(c, L, R, it->first);
        sum = sum + a * b;
    }

    printf("%ld", sum);
    printf("time taken: %.2fs", (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you have to iterate over *all values* in a *map*, there's something wrong with the design. Try to think of another solution entirely. Also might want to pass maps by-reference instead of copying.

Comment: Also, please provide a sample of the file you use that causes the problem.

Comment: `const unordered_map<long int, long int> arr` makes a copy of the map in every call to `counts`. That also seems sub-optimal.

Comment: Thank you, your response is very useful!

Comment: `if(A <= R)` seems to be an optimization which expect only positive numbers, if second array containsnegatives numbers, it seems broken.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the problem says that it only accepts positive integers.